# Unir dos PDF creados con FPDF con PDFMerger en PHP

Tags: php, fpdf

Quiero unir en el código php dos ficheros PDF que he creado con FPDF. Para ello voy a utilizar PDFMerger, que he encontrado la función actualizada en [este repositorio de hithub](https://github.com/myokyawhtun/PDFMerger/blob/master/PDFMerger.php)

El código que he puesto es el siguiente:

```
$pdf->Output($fichero,'F');
$pdf2->Output($fichero2,'F');

$pdfUnido = new PDFMerger;

$pdfUnido->addPDF($pdf->Output($fichero,'F'));
$pdfUnido->addPDF($pdf->Output($fichero2,'F'));

$pdfUnido->merge('download','merged.pdf');
```

Pero algo no esta funcionado bien pues el navegador se queda en blanco.
¿Alguien sabe que está fallando?

Tambien me vale cualquier código que una los dos PDF generados con FPDF.

Un saludo, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final lo he conseguido con el comando gs:

```
$pdf->Output("./documentos/f1.pdf","F");
$pdf->Output("./documentos/f2.pdf","F");

$command= "gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -sOutputFile=merge.pdf ./documentos/f1.pdf ./documentos/f2.pdf";
shell_exec($command);
```